# Is there a way to display variables and display their values from a string coming from an array? Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Tags: batch-file

Keep in mind I'm new to this and quite tired so I may be overlooking/overthinking, crucial/basic/fundamental info. (Which in hindsight an 8 hour youtube video would help)
So what I'm trying to do is pull variable names as strings from an array and display their values.

```
set array[0]=VAR1
set array[1]=VAR2
set array[2]=VAR3
```

These VARs are auto generated by concatenation and assigning them each a value like so.

```
buffer=%VAR%%1%
!buffer!=VAR1_VALUE
```

What I want/need is a way to pull the string from array[0] and display VAR1s Value.
I'm still extremely new to coding and have been piecing stuff together from tutorial sites and trying to math it all out in my head. I'm trying to avoid watching an 8 hour long batch tutorial on youtube to try and fix this single issue I'm having. Call me lazy or non-committal. Truth be told I just want this to work. And am currently debating whether or not I'll commit to the youtube video if this falls through.

I've tried a simple copypasta for loop

```
for /l %%i in (0,1,%NUMBER_OF_VARS%) do (set /a actualCount=%actualCount%+1 &
 echo %VAR%actualCount%%) which returned "actualCount%" 
or !VAR%actualCount%! which returned an error.
```

I have a rudimentary understanding of the exclamation points and percentage signs, but apart from those, I have no clue what I'm dong. Which is to be expected. But ultimately a problem nonetheless.

Comment: ```actualCount=%actualCount%+1``` should have been either ```actualCount=!actualCount!+1```, (if delayed expansion was already enabled), or better ```actualCount=actualCount+1```, or even better ```actualCount += 1```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Let's begin with:

```
set array[1]=VAR1
set array[2]=VAR2
set array[3]=VAR3
set number=3
```

I prefer to start arrays in Batch at index 1 (instead of the C standard 0). Doing that simplify some problems (like *this* one).

If you do this:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%number%) do echo %%i
```

of course the output is 1 2 3 (in separate lines)

Then, do this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,%number%) do echo !array[%%i]!
```

... that show *the values* of array[1..3], that is:

```
VAR1
VAR2
VAR3
```

Now, you want to show *the value* of `VAR1`, `VAR2` and `VAR3`. An *intuitive* answer would be to use:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%number%) do echo !!array[%%i]!!
```

That is, if `!array[%%i]!` is `VAR1` (the first time), then `!!array[%%i]!!` should be `!VAR1!` and hence, the *value* of `VAR1`...

Unfortunately, the *nesting* of several (more than one) exclamation marks do *NOT* works for several levels of Delayed Expansion, so we need to use another way.

The usual method to *repeat* or *nest* another level of processing (for several Batch features) is to use an *additional* `FOR` command; that is, you put in the additional FOR set the value of a *previous* FOR parameter and "complete it" with the extra level of whatever; for example, Delayed Expansion:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,%number%) do (
   for %%v in (!array[%%i]!) do echo !%%v!
)
```

That is, the `%%i` is 1,2,3; the `!array[%%i]!` is *the value* of each element in the array, like `VAR1`, `VAR2`, `VAR3`. Now, note that *the same value* is in the `%%v` parameter of the second FOR, right?

That is, `%%v` is `VAR1`, `VAR2` and `VAR3`. Finally, `!%%v!` is the same as `!VAR1!`, `!VAR2!` and `!VAR3!`; that is, *the values* of the 3 variables. **`;)`**

Please, note that this is *not* an usual management in Batch files. Of course, it works (and more complex things will also work), but you should review if you *really* needs this type of management (or it is just an overcomplicated code that could be simplified)...